# How can I add '^' operator into this Infix to Prefix Conversion, Infix to Postfix Conversion

Tags: java

Can you explain how can I Add?

My Infix is: `1^2+3/3`

Prefix expression is: `+1^2/33` (**which is wrong**)

Postfix expression is: `1^233/+` (**which is wrong**)

the Prefix will be: `+^12/33`

and the Postfix will be: `12^33/+`

My Code:

```
import java.io.*;
class Stack
{
    private char[] a;
    private int top,m;
    public Stack(int max)
    {
        m=max;
        a=new char[m];
        top=-1;
    }
    public void push(char key)
    {
        a[++top]=key;
    }
    public char pop()
    {
        return(a[top--]);
    }
    public char peek()
    {
        return(a[top]);
    }
    public boolean isEmpty()
    {
        return (top==-1);
    }
}

class Evaluation
{
    private Stack s;
    private String input;
    private String output="";
    public Evaluation(String str)
    {
        input=str;
        s=new Stack(str.length());
    }

    public String inToPre()
    {
        for(int i=input.length()-1;i>=0;i--)
        {
            char ch=input.charAt(i);
            **switch(ch)
            {
            case '+':
            case '-':gotOperator(ch,1,')');
            break;
            case '*':
            case '/':gotOperator(ch,2,')');
            break;
            case ')':s.push(ch);
            break;
            case '(':gotParenthesis(')');
            break;
            default:output=ch+output;
            }
        }
        while(!s.isEmpty())
            output=s.pop()+output;
        return output;
    } // End to inToPre

    public String inToPost()
    {
        for(int i=0;i<input.length();i++)
        {
            char ch=input.charAt(i);
            switch(ch)
            {
            case '+':
            case '-':gotOperator(ch,1,'(');
            break;
            case '*':
            case '/':gotOperator(ch,2,'(');
            break;
            case '(':s.push(ch);
            break;
            case ')':gotParenthesis('(');
            break;
            default:output=output+ch;
            }
        }
        while(!s.isEmpty())
            output=output+s.pop();
        return output;
    } // End inToPost**

    private void gotOperator(char opThis,int prec1,char x)
    {
        while(!s.isEmpty())
        {
            char opTop=s.pop();
            if(opTop==x)
            {
                s.push(opTop);
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                int prec2;
                if(opTop=='+'||opTop=='-')
                    prec2=1;
                else
                    prec2=2;
                if(prec2<prec1&&x=='(')
                {
                    s.push(opTop);
                    break;
                }
                else if(prec2<=prec1&&x==')')
                {
                    s.push(opTop);
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    if(x==')')
                        output=opTop+output;
                    else
                        output=output+opTop;
                }
            }
        } // End While gotOperator
        s.push(opThis);
    } // End gotOperator

    private void gotParenthesis(char x)
    {
        while(!s.isEmpty())
        {
            char ch=s.pop();
            if(ch==x)
                break;
            else
            {
                if(x==')')
                    output=ch+output;
                else
                    output=output+ch;
            } // End Else
        } // End While gotParenthesis
    } // End gotParenthesis
} // End Class Evaluation
```

Comment: Sometimes I wish Stack Overflow allowed reaction image macros...

Comment: Between your problem description and your code style choices, I find it very difficult to understand what it is you're trying to do and what you need help with.

Comment: Do I post the whole code?

Comment: I already know the answer for my questions. :)

Answer (score 1):

Just looking at your code quickly I can see that in the InFix analysis you are not considering a new level for the ^ operator.

The groups should be +-, */, ^. Since the ^ has higher priority.

Regards

Comment: Can you explain how can I add the case '^': operator?

Comment: The same way you did with +- and */, create a case for it and working with precedence 3, so creating a prec3 and replicating the same logic.

Comment: To make it neater you should follow a recursive approach, this way you avoid an explicit stack (you have one for free ;)). Take a look at [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser). That way is also easer to add new operators (with different precedence).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the point of precedence. Isn't the point of polish notation to define an unambiguous system given any binary operators. independant of any order of operations?

Comment: Like this?`case '^':gotOperator(ch,3,'(');`

Comment: Yes but you need to analyze the inFix expression (taking the precedence into accoount) to generate the Polish notation (it doesn't come for free).

Comment: @RonnelYatco Yes and also you have to fix the gotOperator, to take into account the new precedence=3.

Comment: But then again I continue to push toward the recursive variant.

Comment: is this correct @luiso1979 `int prec2;
    if(opTop=='+'||opTop=='-')
     prec2=1;
    else if(opTop=='*'||opTop=='/')
     prec2=2;
    else
     prec2=3;`

Comment: @RonnelYatco, It seems so. This [site](http://www.technical-recipes.com/2011/a-mathematical-expression-parser-in-java-and-cpp/) maybe helpful, it has an implementation similar to yours.

Comment: `case '*':
        case '/':
        case '^':gotOperator(ch,2,')');`


that's the answer! :)

Same for the Postfix method.

Thanks for your support!!